# Floating the auto generated HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got following auto generated HTML, which I can not change. 
This HTML displays the message in `em` before the `input` field, however I need to move it to the right side of the input field.

I have tried using float right to the `em`, but it does not work.
I'll appreciate any help.

```
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="user_email">Email</label>
        <em>Email is required.</em> 
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" id="user_email" name="user_email">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: maybe you should float it to the left, instead then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS Only solution (which I don't recommend, but works)**

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rLhTs/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="user_email">Email</label>
            <em>Email is required.</em> 
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" id="user_email" name="user_email">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="user_name">Name</label>
            <em>Name is required.</em> 
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" id="name_email" name="name_email">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
​.form-field:nth-child(1):after { 
    content:"Email is required.";
}

.form-field:nth-child(2):after { 
    content:"Name is required.";
}
```

​
You'll just have to declare the `:after` content for `nth-child` and you'll need to know specifically what you're trying to replace.

**This is a JavaScript solution:**

Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E8dJ9/3/

I've expanded it to show you it could work for any number of rows. You may have to refine this a bit depending on your real specific use case.

And the code for completeness:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="user_email">Email</label>
            <em>Email is required.</em> 
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" id="user_email" name="user_email">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="user_name">Name</label>
            <em>Name is required.</em> 
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" id="user_name" name="user_name">
        </td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$('th[scope="row"]').each(function(index, value) {
    var em = $(this).find('em').text();
    $(this).parent().find('td').append('<em>' + em + '</em>');
});​
```

CSS:

```
.form-field th em {
    display: none;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm looking for CSS solution.

Comment: What I don't like about the CSS-only version is that 1) since a `float` won't work for you, the `DOM` isn't being represented properly, 2) it's cumbersome and not very flexible, and 3) generally speaking, `CSS` is best used for presentation, not for writing content. But I maybe somehow you're working within certain restrictions that make it impossible to using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
​label {
    float:left;
}
em {
    float: right;
}
input {
    float:left;
}
```

​Although this will put the `em` on the farthest right spot of the parent container.  Considering it is in a table it might work as is, can't test unless we have the full HTML with the opening table tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to do, use HTML5 validation for email in the input field

<input type="email" title="enter the email in correct format" required="true"/>
whenever the user clicks the submit button without entering the email or entered the email in wrong format, the form will not be submitted and error will be displayed.